# Looking to dynamically exclude code blocks form a bundle at build time with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I need to be able to conditionally build a product, it's a single code base whitelabled for numerous clients and the use case exists that a certain component or set of components needs to only exist for a single client instance.

I have found a number of webpack loaders that do take care of this, but they rely on comments which are stripped out of the react DOM, and none of the config options I know of in webpack managed to get to the code before this point

```
  {
    enforce: 'pre',
    test: /\.(tsx?|js)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "webpack-remove-block-loader",
        options: {
          active: true, // Boolean. loader on or off
          start: "{/*", // String.
          end: "*/}", // String.
          blocks: ['client'+argv.entryCode], // Array.
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Is there a way I am not thinking of to run this on the pure tsx or perhaps preserve the required comments somehow?

Alternatively any other way to manage something like this. In most cases it will be a client specific component but there could also be certain helper function that would need to be excluded for which the above webpack loader should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just conditionally add the whole rule.

Something like this:

```
if (active) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    // ...the rule you posted in your question
  })
}
```

or

```
rules: [
  active && {
    // ...the rule you posted in your question
  },
]
```